# Getting the value of duplicate nodes in XML?

Tags: ruby, xml

How can I get the values of two nodes if they have the same name, using LibXML for Ruby, or any other Ruby library? I have this XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<test>
  <test1>
    <foo>534569</foo>
  </test1>
  <test1>
    <foo>534570</foo>
  </test1>
</test>
```

I want both values of `foo`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `find` method, which will return all nodes that match the specified xpath.

Below is an example of how to output the content of each foo element:

```
require 'libxml'

xml_sample = %q[<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<test>
  <test1>
    <foo>534569</foo>
  </test1>
  <test1>
    <foo>534570</foo>
  </test1>
</test>]

doc = LibXML::XML::Document.string(xml_sample)
doc.find('test1/foo').each{ |foo| puts foo.content }
#=> 534569
#=> 534570
```

Answer (score 2):

Personally, I'd recommend using [Nokogiri](http://nokogiri.org). It's become the defacto standard for XML/HTML parsing in Ruby.

```
require 'nokogiri'

doc = Nokogiri::XML(<<EOT)
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<test>
  <test1>
    <foo>534569</foo>
  </test1>
  <test1>
    <foo>534570</foo>
  </test1>
</test>
EOT

doc.search('foo').map(&:text)
```

which returns:

```
[
    [0] "534569",
    [1] "534570"
]
```